# Xamarin.Android immediately terminates

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]

Can someone please explain what's going on with my newly created Xamarin Xaml Portable project? When in "Debug" the application terminates immediately as soon as I lunch it -- like the gif above.

When in Release, it runs -- like the gif below

[image]

I like to understand what's going on between Debug and in Release why when in Debug, it terminates immediately but not in Release.

My phone model is [Oppo A37F](http://www.gsmarena.com/oppo_a37-8162.php) - Android 5.1

Another confusion is that, I have a Samsung Galaxy S DUOS 2, that is flashed with a custom fimrware - Android 6 (Marshmallow) - I am not facing the Debug/Release issue with this one.

Turning off/on my PC and Android devices does not help as well.

Thank you

Comment: In Xamarin android you need to set preferences for the particular build `64-84x` or related to your device.

Comment: @Smit - My Oppo device is Quad-core 1.2 GHz Cortex-A53, not sure if this is running on x86 or x64

Comment: ok it's 64bit... https://www.qualcomm.com/products/snapdragon/processors/410

Comment: still behaves on Debug - x64 -- it terminates instantly

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55666/app-runs-in-debug-mode-crashes-in-release-mode Look a this ref. I understand it is for release mode. But it might give u a hint.

Comment: Is it something to do with app permissions? Check your app in the Application manager and see if there's any permissions which it needs but are disabled.

Comment: It's now working @Smit - Check the answer

Answer (score 1):

[image]

and so I got it to work. Thanks @[Smit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5809504/smit) for the direction

I have to set "**Sdk Assemblies Only**" in Debug.. The default setting is set to "None"

Answer (score 0):

Clean your solution then uninstall the application on your device or emulator
and deploy your solution, that solved my problem.